# Can I board at a different train station with a tatkal ticket in India?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, regulations, tatkal

I have booked two tickets for Mumbai to Pune in Tatkal quota.
The train departs from Mumbai CST, can I board the train at Dadar station?

Comment: We have answers saying yes, answers saying no and answers saying sometimes, none of them backed up by anything more than personal experience. It would be really helpful if somebody could post an answer that cited authoritative sources such as railway company policies.

Answer (score 7):

No.

If the TTR checks for your ticket before the train halts at Dadar, he will cancel your ticket.  To solve this, you can change your boarding point by visiting any station.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have an official source to back this up, but when I used to travel Indian Railways from Mumbai, I boarded at Kalyan or Dadar (when my ticket said CST) and it was fine. IIRC the ticket inspector told me that after one station, they mark the passenger as a no-show and give the seat away. In any case, inspection didn't start until Dadar or Kalyan.

Disclaimer: This was over 7 years ago.

Comment: As per railway rules, the TTR will wait for one station. And if the person didn't show up after that, the seat can be allotted RAC/GEN passengers. If DADAR is the next station to CSTM, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.
Dadar is the very next stop after Mumbai CST, there will not be any problem.
You can catch your train up to Thane.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Per Ansari's answer and the one-stop rule, this is actually correct.

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed Tatkal Tikets can't be canceled and no refund is permitted in Confirmed Tatkal Tkt. Therefore, general boarding rule can't be made applicable to confirmed Tatkal Tkt. Confirmed Tatkal berth should remain vacant for the passenger holding confirmed Tatkal Tkt.

It is based on the logic that railway can't make profits twice by selling a confirmed tatkal ticket which can't be canceled or no refund is allowed. 
I am not finding rule on the subject. So one has to get clarification from railway or to challenge in court.