# Boarding a train in India at another station

Tags: trains, tickets, india, indian-railways

I have booked a ticket on a train from Mumbai to Chennai and boarding at Pune. Since my schedules have changed, I will be in Mumbai on that day. Can I board the same train in Mumbai in my own ticket and claim the seat/berth?

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/can-i-board-at-a-different-train-station-with-a-tatkal-ticket-in-india?rq=1 (slightly different situation, though)

Comment: Don't know about India specifically but I assume that a ticket from Pune to Chennai does not entitle you to travel on a *longer* route, at least not with paying something extra. And the seat could conceivably be assigned to someone else between Mumbai and Pune.

Comment: I don't see any reason that you cannot board the train at mumbai, as the fare in any case would be the same. The only thing is you cannot claim your seat until Pune. TT should not penalize you for entering train at Mumbai. -Akshay

Answer (score 15):

No, you can't. Simply because the train is from Mumbai and you're boarding at Pune doesn't mean your seat will be empty on the Mumbai to Pune leg.

[Changes of boarding station](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html) are only allowed if the station you want to get on at falls *later* than the one mentioned on your ticket.

> **CHANGE OF BOARDING POINT**
>
> If a passenger desires to occupy reserved
>   accommodation from any station enroute, he would be permitted to
>   entrain at any intermediate station he chooses irrespective of the
>   distance from the starting station subject to the following conditions:
>
> - A specific request must be made in writing at the station from where the ticket is purchased and reservation made at least 24 hours before the scheduled departure of the train from the starting station.
> - The Railway Administration reserves the right to use such accommodation from the originating station up to the station at which the passenger is due to entrain.
> - No refund will be permissible for the portion of journey not performed by the passenger.

Unfortunately, in this case it means you need to book a new ticket. If you already have a confirmed Pune - Chennai leg, I'd recommend just buying a Mumbai - Pune leg.

Comment: now this rules slightly changed because of total computerization of all major stations: _A specific request must be made in writing **at any computerized reservation counter** and reservation made atleast 24 hours before the scheduled departure of the train from the starting station._