# Change of boarding point on Indian Railways train

Tags: trains, tickets, india, indian-railways

I booked a train ticket on the Yeswantpur (Yeshvantapur, YPR) to Pondicherry (Puducherry, ODY) [route](http://24coaches.com/kerala-bangalore-trains/). I gave my boarding point as Hosur. My reservation is from Yeswantpur. Am I entitled to board at Banaswadi (BAND) or Krishnarajapuram (KR Puram, KJR)?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22114/46

Answer (score 2):

No,

If TC will find the seat is vacant from Hosur then He can give it to next waiting passengers.
You need to change your Boarding point again.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, but you have to inform IR at least 24 hours in advance, otherwise you may lose your seat.

See this answer: [Boarding point change for an Indian rail reservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26261/boarding-point-change-for-an-indian-rail-reservation)