# Boarding point change for an Indian rail reservation

Tags: trains, india

I booked a train ticket on the Yeswantpur (Yeshvantapur, YPR) to Calicut (CLT). I gave my boarding point as Yesvantpur (YPR). My reservation is from Yeswantpur. Am I entitled to board at Karmelram (CRLM)?

Answer (score 2):

You can board a train at any point along the route, as long as it's after your original departure point and you notify IR in advance.  [Reservation rules](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html):

> **CHANGE OF BOARDING POINT :**
>
> If a passenger desires to occupy reserved
> accommodation from any station enroute, he would be permitted to
> entrain at any intermediate station he chooses irrespective of the
> distance from the starting station subject to the following conditions
> :
>
> - A specific request must be made in writing at the station from where
>   the ticket is purchased and reservation made atleast 24 hours before
>   the scheduled departure of the train from the starting station.
> - The
>   Railway Administration reserves the right to use such accommodation
>   from the originating station up to the station at which the passenger
>   is due to entrain.
> - No refund will be permissible for the portion of
>   journey not performed by the passenger.

Comment: Just a note: From my personal experience as an Indian, no one ask for the written permission. I didn't even know about the permission system before reading this answer.