# Can I board the train before the specified boarding point if I have a reservation?

Tags: india, irctc

In Indian railway reservation, while reserving tickets, we can select a particular station as boarding point (we can chose a **from**, a **to** and an optional boarding point). The boarding point indicates that we are going to board the train from that station only even if we have a reservation from a previous station. This prevents the Train Ticket Examiner from giving the seat to some other person until the station after the specified boarding point.

My question is, can I board the train before the specified boarding point if I book from there?

Not a dupe of [Boarding point change for an Indian rail reservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26261/boarding-point-change-for-an-indian-rail-reservation). I am aware of the feature to change boarding point. But while chart prepared, it is impossible to change it.

Comment: What an interesting question. Are the fares different for those two stations?

Comment: yes. The reservation with different boarding point is mainly to overcome the quota limitations. @HankyPanky

Answer (score 4):

Most probably, you won't be able to. Let's see it this way. Suppose the train is going these stations A, B and C. You booked a ticket from A to C while your boarding is B. So if you want to board at the station A from where you have booked the ticket, There are 90% chances that that seat has been reserved for somebody else who is travelling from A to B.

So basically it all depends on the route and availability of the seat. If the train route is short you should be able to board at station A.

Answer (score 2):

No we can not board before boarding point.
My experience I booked a ticket from Maniyachi station to Egmore Chennai and opt to board at Kovilpatti in Pearl city express.

But due to unavoidable circumstance I boarded at Maniyachi itself.
While TTR checking he informed it is liable to impose penalty and warned me. I am not eligible to travel between Maniyachi and Kovilpatti he added.

Comment: Welcome to the site Somasundaram. Please remember that on internet, all capital letters is seen as shouting. You will see that most posts on this site only have capital letters at the start of sentences and at the start of names, and that is what we like.