# Booking from different initiating station to get cornfirm tickets

Tags: tickets, bookings, train-stations, indian-railways

I was booking ticket from Viramgam Junction to Madgaon as cornfirm tickets are available, however I will board from Khed which is more than 500 km from Viramgam. Will there be any problem even if I mentioned boarding station Khed while booking?

Comment: What's a "cornfirm ticket"? 

Comment: Possibly related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19574/can-i-board-at-a-different-train-station-with-a-tatkal-ticket-in-india

Comment: Surely it means "confirmed ticket."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fairly common to book tickets from a different source station to get confirmed berths. IRCTC allows you to change the boarding station before 24 hours of the scheduled departure of the train. Please read this [page](http://contents.irctc.co.in/en/boardingPointChange.html) for complete details.